# How to calculate the average values of a year from quarterly data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and I want to calculate the average number of each year

```
index   cath_date
1   2017Q4  111
2   2017Q3  107
3   2018Q2  105
4   2017Q2  105
5   2017Q1  101
7   2018Q3  98
8   2016Q3  97
9   2018Q1  94
10  2018Q4  91
11  2016Q1  91
12  2015Q4  85
13  2016Q4  83
14  2016Q2  81
15  2015Q3  80
16  2015Q2  67
18  2015Q1  28
```

Finally to have a dataframe like this

```
index   cath_date
1   2015    28
2   2016    87
3   2017    87
4   2018    97
```

Comment: You need to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried yet

Comment: I do not have an idea to provide an example

Answer (score 4):

Your math seems a little funky (e.g., `2015` has a minimum value of 28, so how could the mean be 28?), but you can just `.groupby` the first 4 characters and calculate the mean:

```
In [6]: df.groupby(df['index'].str.slice(0, 4)).mean()
Out[6]:
       cath_date
index
2015          65
2016          88
2017         106
2018          97
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df.groupby(df['index'].apply(lambda i:i[:4]))['cath_date'].mean().reset_index()
```